# SSL handshake across multiple devices

Tags: ssl

A fairly basic SSL question, if you don't mind:

Lets say I have traffic flow from a client to a web server as follows:

[client] --> [public SLB:80] --> [reverse proxy:80] --> [internal SLB:80] --> [webserver:443]

Will parts of the traffic as it traverse this topology be unencrypted or will the SSL handshake succeed when a request finally lands at the web server?

I am trying to determine if I need SSL certs installed on each device in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last link in your chain will (likely) be encrypted. Everything before that will be unencrypted. So you only need certs on the last box.

By design connections on port 80 are unencrypted, normal clients will not try to make an SSL connection.

Comment: Thanks Iain. Just to make sure I understand: If the client tries to make a SSL connection using https://, the connection will be encrypted, even though the SLBs and reverse proxy in between do not make use of SSL? Also, if the client does not make use of SSL, just normal http://, but the internal SLB redirects the request to https on the web server, that will also ensure the SSL handshake succeeds? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you understand at all and that's your problem.

Comment: Probably true! With my limited knowledge, I am of the opinion that as long as the final web server is correctly configured with SSL certs, etc. The communication between the client and the web server will be encrypted. I have seen different views on that, hence my basic question here.